# SQL Format date to YYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000

Tags: sql-server, date, casting, format

I have multiple dates and I would like to set Hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero in the SELECT.

For instance : 2017-10-10 15:23:28.603 becomes 2017-10-10 00:00:00.000

So far I could set everything to zero expect Hours.

```
dateadd(hour, datepart(hour,getdate()),CAST(convert(varchar(20),getdate(),112) as datetime)) AS 'Date',
```

Gives : 2017-10-10 15:00:00.000, how to get rid of the hours too ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just cast to date and back

```
SELECT GETDATE(), CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS date) AS datetime)
```

gives

```
2018-06-05 10:53:41.937    2018-06-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: I get this error : "String or binary data would be truncated"

Comment: Then post your real code because you can't get the error with my code: no strings or binary data

Comment: @Benoît Add some sample data in your question (as **text**) that produces your error.

Comment: Sounds like the error is occurring from a different part of your T-SQL though; not @gbn 's solution (which, like he said, cannot generate that error, as a `date(time)` datatype can't suffer truncation).

Comment: I will try to add some sample data, but the query is 500 lines long, I'm trying to make it simpler to explain.